# Mongoose model: calculate and automatically update average rating

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a Movie model in Mongoose and this has a ratings key which is an array of numbers. I am looking for some sort of method I can add to this schema that automatically calculates the average rating when I add a new rating to the array. Does anyone know how this is done?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    actors: String,
    director: String,
    length: Number,
    description: String,
    genre: String,
    country: String,
    year: Number,
    ratings: [],
    averageRating: Number,
    reviews: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Review'}],
    pictureUrl: String
}, { usePushEach: true });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Movie', schema);
```

Comment: `getters / setters` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a [method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/methods-statics.html) on the schema to do two things: add a rating to the `ratings` property, and then update the `averageRatings` property. You would then call this method instead of directly updating the `ratings` property.